# OLS regression - properties

Tags: statistics, regression, regression-analysis

When doing an OLS regression of the form $Y_{i}=\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}X_{i}+u_{i}$, one of the properties we get from the normal equations is that:

$$\sum u_{i}X_{i}=0$$

How can I show this without the use of the normal equations?

Comment: What do you mean by "without using the normal equation"? This is a property of the OLS algorithm, not some general truth.

Comment: @A.E, thanks for your answer. In my exam I was asked to show that this is true, without deriving normal equations of the OLS procedure. I'm guessing there is a way to replace $u_{i}$ by some terms which leads us to get 0 as a result.